# sharing property between forms in vb

Tags: vb.net

I've to pass the property between two forms.in Form2:i've created property IsFilterEnabled and accessing this in formmain

```
 Public Property IsFilterEnabled() As Boolean
        Get
            Return mIsEnabled
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
            mIsEnabled = Value
        End Set
    End Property
  Public Sub FilterButton_Click() Handles FilterButton.Click
        Dim currentRow As Data.DataRow
        If vessel_NameComboBox.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            mIsEnabled = True
            formMain.LoadData()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Formmain

```
Dim frm2 As New Form2
If frm2.IsFilterEnabled = True Then End
```

Data is lost IsFilterEnabled property as im creating new instance of form2.How to get the same instance of form2 in formmain to access the propery

Comment: Google your title first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your property a global scope, shareable between other members, by using the `Shared` keyword when declaring it.

```
Public Class Form2 : Inherits Form

    Public Shared Property MyProperty As Object

End Class
```

Then you can access the shared value anytime:

```
Public Class Form1 : Inherits Form

    Form2.MyProperty = "1st Hello World!"

    Dim f As New Form2
    f.MyProperty = "2nd Hello World!"
    f.Show()
    f.Dispose()

    MsgBox(Form2.MyProperty.ToString)

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..but i need to set the property value of MyProperty="1st Hello World!" in form2 itself..when i create   Dim f As New Form2 in form1,the data is lost

Comment: as per my code,i've set  mIsEnabled  in form2 itself Public Sub FilterButton_Click() Handles FilterButton.Click
        Dim currentRow As Data.DataRow
        If vessel_NameComboBox.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            mIsEnabled = True
            formMain.LoadData()
        End If
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Pass the property in the constructor of Form2.

```
Public Sub New(enabled As Boolean)
    InitializeComponent()

    'Process using enabled arg
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I access form2 in formmain without creating new instance not to loose data

Comment: @Priya Instantiate your new Form2 privately, that way you can keep track of and access the same instance.

Comment: ive tried instantiating in form2..but still its not accesible in formmain